# Find Clusters of Points Among Table of (X, Y) Coordinates

Tags: sql, t-sql, geometry

Assume I have a table called Points containing (x, y) coordinates as follows:

| PointID | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 20 |
| 2 | 11 | 20 |
| 3 | 10 | 18 |
| 4 | 51 | 13 |
| 5 | 18 | 19 |

I’m looking for some reasonably efficient way to output a list of clusters from this table along with a size. In the table above, the first three points are in close proximity to one another, so they would be part of a single cluster. If you put a circle with a radius of (say) 5 around any of those points, each point will have the other two points in its “circle.”

Some definitions are in order.

- A *cluster* would be a grouping of n or more points (ID’s) in close proximity to one another. n would be larger in the scaled solution (here it's 3 for illustrative purposes).
- The *cluster size* could be the number of points in the cluster or, better yet, take the point in the cluster having the greatest number of points within in its circle -- whatever that value is would be the cluster size.

One possible output could be a Clusters and ClusterPoints table as follows:

Clusters

| ClusterID | Size |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 2 |

ClusterPoints

| ClusterID | PointID |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 |
| 10 | 2 |
| 10 | 3 |

These are SQL tables, and I think I'm looking at a T-SQL or SQL program to output the tables, though I think I can adapt any pseudocode. Do generic algorithms exist for this kind of thing? If not, thoughts on how to implement? Thanks.

Comment: What if you have three points, where A is <5 from B, and B <5 from C, but A to C is >5?

Comment: Good comment. I feel like the first task is to assign a value x to each point, where x is the number of "neighbors" within its radius. Then basically drop all the points where x < n, n being the threshold value I mentioned in my post. At that point the map should show the clusters without the noise, and the challenge becomes assigning the remaining points to clusters.

Answer (score 1):

An approach is to loop through each point to find all other points which intersect based on radius, then average those points to determine cluster center point. Centre point will be same for other points in cluster, then de-duplicate.
Can also run across a list of radius.

```
declare @ClusterRadius table (RadiusID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, radius float)
insert into @ClusterRadius values (5)
insert into @ClusterRadius values (10)
insert into @ClusterRadius values (20)
insert into @ClusterRadius values (50)

declare @points table (PointID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, point geometry)
insert into @points values (geometry::Point(10,20,0))
insert into @points values (geometry::Point(11,20,0))
insert into @points values (geometry::Point(10,18,0))
insert into @points values (geometry::Point(51,13,0))
insert into @points values (geometry::Point(18,19,0))

declare @tempclusters table (ClusterID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,PointIDsInCluster varchar(50), clusterradius int, x float, y float, size int)
declare @clusters table (ClusterID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,PointIDsInCluster varchar(50), clusterradius int, clustercentrepoint geometry, size int)
DECLARE @PCounter INT, @RCounter int, @radius float
set @RCounter = 1
WHILE (@RCounter <= (select count(*) from @ClusterRadius)) -- Loop through all radius
BEGIN
    select @radius = radius from @ClusterRadius where RadiusID = @RCounter
    set @PCounter = 1
    WHILE (@PCounter <= (select count(*) from @points)) -- loop through all points
    BEGIN
        -- For each point find all points which interect based on radius, then average those pints for cluster center point. Centre point will be same for other points in cluster.
            -- Find cluster center by average of points: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_finite_set_of_points 
            insert into @tempclusters
                select STRING_AGG(cast(p2.PointID as varchar(50)), ', ') as PointIDsInCluster
                        , @radius as r, avg(p2.point.STX) as x,avg(p2.point.STY) as y, count(*) as count
                        from @points p1
                    outer apply (select * from @points) p2
                    where p1.PointID = @PCounter and p1.point.STBuffer(@radius).STIntersects(p2.point) = 1
                    group by p1.PointID
                    --having count(*) > 1 
        SET @PCounter  = @PCounter  + 1
    end
    SET @RCounter  = @RCounter  + 1
end

-- De-duplicate and convert x/y to point
insert into @clusters
    Select PointIDsInCluster, clusterradius, geometry::Point(x,y,0), size 
    from (select distinct PointIDsInCluster, clusterradius, x, y, size from @tempclusters) a

-- Visualise clusters
select clustercentrepoint.STBuffer(clusterradius) as ClustersAndRadius from @clusters 

-- View data
select ClusterID, PointIDsInCluster, ClusterRadius, clustercentrepoint.ToString() as ClusterCenterPoint, Size  from @clusters
order by 3, 5 desc

---- Map clusters back to original points
-- ...string_split(@PointIDsInCluster,',')
```

[image]

[image]